# Ways to make a straight in poker

Tags: combinatorics, games

A deck is 4 suits of 13 cards each. The ace is both low and high so that is why you have 10 ways to make a straight.

A flush is all cards of the same suite.  There are two hands (flush and full house) between straight and straight-flush so this is why they are broken out.

I am not able to follow the calculation for number of way to make a straight (excluding straight flush) from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability)

$\binom{10}{1} \binom{4}{1}^5 - \binom{10}{1} \binom{4}{1}$

The part I don't get is the $\binom{4}{1}^5$
Where does that come from?

Is that 4 suits and 5 cards?  Even if so I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a keen poker player but I believe this refers to the possibility of selecting a card from each of the four suits. For each of the five cards in the straight, this can be done in $\binom{4}{1} = 4$ ways . For instance, for a straight of 1,2,3,4,5 there are four fives among which you can choose. And likewise for the rest of the cards.

Also, a word about the $\binom{10}{1}$ factor. This accounts for the number of ways one can select five *adjacent* cards out of the thirteen, there are nine ways to do so, **plus** the possibility of selecting the last four cards *and* having a high ace, which still counts as a straight I hear. In all, 10 ways.

Comment: +1 And "$-{10 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}$" discounts the straight flush, and its subset, the royal flush.